# Handling errors and callbacks in API Gateway Lambda Proxy

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

First of all I got the basic stuff working of connecting API Gateway and Lambda(with Lambda Proxy Integration). I tried a POST request. I got a 200 response from callback(null, response_success). 
When I tried to do more operations in my Lambda code, I am getting 502 error.

What I did extra from my previous step(where I successfully got response from Lambda for my POST request): 
I simply wrapped few pieces of code inside functions and used callbacks(these are normal nodejs stuff). Added few functions. At the end I do return callback(null, response_success). Where response_success has statusCode, headers, body.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

functions(){
 //I tried to do callback from here after finishing all my operations, no luck!
}    
callback(null, response_success);
});
```

Also in this case my event.body becomes NULL, if that helps! 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The limited example you are showing would likely cause your last callback statement to fire prematurely.  Remember, execution doesn't block when you start asynchronous operations... it continues.

Comment: Well, for synchronous stuff there is no issue here. but i guess i need to use the header 'X-Amz-Invocation-Type' in order for this to work.